# Ignorar registros vacios de una consulta SELECT

Tags: javascript, html, sql, vue.js

estoy trabajando sobre un proyecto con js y quiero cargar un selector, el problema es que en la base de datos en sqlServer hay registros que tienen campos vacios principalmente las claves primarias y quisiera que solo se mostraras aquellos registros que no tengan campos vacios, esta es mi consulta sql:

```
select 
 cod_variedad_rotulada as label,
 cod_variedad_rotulada as value
 FROM dev_auto_variedad_rotulada
 WHERE cod_temporada = @cod_temporada
```

Comment: Añadir a la consulta ` AND (clave_primaria IS NOT NULL OR clave_primaria <> '')` debería mitigar eso del lado de la consulta. Que el campo mismo no debería dejar insertar valores vacíos o nulos pero eso es otra cosa.

Comment: @Alfabravo solo necesita `AND clave_primaria <> ''` porque eso también elimina los nulos.

Comment: Muchas gracias! este me sirvió!

Comment: Como mencionan arriba puedes usar cualquiera de esos métodos, incluso lo más básico como where clave_primaria != ' '. Debes hacer varias validaciones y ver que tipo de dato esta nulo o vacio porque son dos cosas diferentes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hola a tu consulta de hace falta la exclusión/"no igual" de valores nulos y vacíos:

tu consulta:

```
select 
 cod_variedad_rotulada as label,
 cod_variedad_rotulada as value
 FROM dev_auto_variedad_rotulada
 WHERE cod_temporada = @cod_temporada
```

La consulta actualizada:

```
select 
 cod_variedad_rotulada as label,
 cod_variedad_rotulada as value
 FROM dev_auto_variedad_rotulada
 WHERE cod_temporada = @cod_temporada AND clave_primaria <> ''
```

Documentación:
https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/queries/search-condition-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/operators?hl=es-419